# Elasticsearch wont index nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I created an explicit mapping with this structure:

```
[
    'index' => 'order',
    'body' => [
        "mappings" => [
            "properties" => [
                "order" => [
                    "id" => [
                        "type" => "keyword"
                    ],
                    "basket" => [
                        "type" => "nested",
                        "dynamic" => "strict",
                        "properties" => [
                            "status" => [
                                "type" => "keyword"
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],

                    "created" => [
                        "type" => "date",
                        "format" => "epoch_second"
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

everything is OK with indexing, but Kibana says the nested field was not indexed (unindexed field can not be searched):
[image: Kibana result]

result of index looks normally:

[image]

Comment: What is the ES/Kibana version?

Comment: @TusharShahi 7.13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not yet [supported](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084) for nested fields.

One work around mentioned is using "[include_in_parent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-params)".

> One trick you can use is "include_in_parent" setting in Elasticsearch mappings, which flattens the schema at index time.

This adds the field to the parent document after flattening it.

Comment: The `basket` field is actually an array, so I can't use flattened field.

Comment: This will probably give you unexpected results. I don't think there is a way, as you can see in the github issue.